# Using array to fill drop down

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a select that Id e to fill the options with a array. I'm not quite getting how to do it. Currently I'm trying this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<select>
  <?php  $theArr = array("Home", "Events", "Bio", "Contact");?>
  <?php foreach ($theArr as $menu_option){ ?>
    <option><?php $menu_option; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

but all I'm getting is a empty drop down, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You need to echo the `$menu_option` variable.

Comment: Use just `<option><?=$menu_option; ?></option>`. It will do the job.

Comment: just `echo` is missing and 3 answer given for that. ha ha ha

Comment: what is this <?= in relation to <?php echo I've never see it written like that. Is it just a fancy shorthand?Either way it works and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `echo` for display output. Change your drop down as below:

```
<select>
  <?php  $theArr = array("Home", "Events", "Bio", "Contact");?>
  <?php foreach ($theArr as $menu_option){ ?>
    <option><?php echo $menu_option; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting anything

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head> <!-- also close your head -->
    <body>
        <select>
            <?php  $theArr = array("Home", "Events", "Bio", "Contact");?>
            <?php foreach ($theArr as $menu_option){ ?>
            <option><?php echo $menu_option; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to add `echo` to your code, or `print_r` to make sure that the results are being printed. OR you can simply use `<?=$menu_options;?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing echo statement

```
enter code here
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
<?php  $theArr = array("Home", "Events", "Bio", "Contact");?>
<?php foreach ($theArr as $menu_option){ ?>
  <option><?php echo $menu_option; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `echo` :)

```
<select>
    <?php  $theArr = array("Home", "Events", "Bio", "Contact");?>
    <?php foreach ($theArr as $menu_option): ?>
    <option><?php echo $menu_option; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

I also change your `{}` to much easier to read.